# Dual boot Linux / Windows. How to deny completely Windows?

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot

I have a dual boot setup (Debian / Ubuntu and Windows) on my laptop.

I would like GRUB to start Linux automatically, without a prompt for Windows. And eventually start Windows only with (for example) a combination of keys.

Or have some rows of fake entries installed and at 3rd/4th/nth place Win (with a fake name, eg. "Restart Now").

My goal: if an inexperienced person boots my laptop, he can not boot Windows.

Comment: The easiest way to do this is to just set your bootloader to automatically load Debian at boot after a few seconds. Then, you would be able to interrupt the count-down and boot Windows if you so chose.

Comment: OK, I could set at 1 sec. But is it possible to fill the bootlodader with several fake voices?

Comment: Fake voices? You mean fake entries? If not, what do you mean?

Comment: Yes, i mean fake entries...

Comment: Maybe you wouldn't need to do any of that if you did away with automatic login in windows and set a password.

Answer (score 2):

Adding fake entries or some hidden keystrokes are **NOT** secure. If you don't want someone to boot Windows on your computer, then adding protection only for newbies is not sufficient. I can't imagine a case where you don't want to protect from experienced people, but only from newbies.

As a solution, I would password protect the bootloader (you use GRUB2, right?). It will allow you to protect specific entries, so it will require a password to boot Windows, but it won't require a password for any other entries (Ubuntu, Debian or whatever). There is an excellent [HOWTO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords) on the Ubuntu Wiki.

**NOTE:** this still doesn't stop a prepared person from booting a LiveCD, retrieve the bootloader password and boot Windows. To prevent this, you have to add a BIOS password and set the HDD as the first bootable device in your BIOS. You may want to read further on physical security. There is a good [HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Security-HOWTO/physical-security.html) on it on TLDP (the bootloader section is a bit outdated, refer to the wiki page I linked above).

Comment: @pasimon it is not a problem of security... Simply I don't need strong security, simply render windows "invisible", in manner that you can enter it only selecting a fake entry (e.g. called "Restart" instead of "windows 7") or, my hope, that laptop start every time with linux directly, but if you press (for example!) CTRL - ALT - P (it is, repeat, only an example) GRUB appear...

Comment: Then all you have to do is to rename the Windows menu entry. There's a good tutorial [here](http://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2011/03/09/grub2-revisited/).